# Checking whether $w = f(z)$ is conformal and its mapping?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I was thinking about the conformal map $w =f(z)$ in which $f$ satisfies $w = f(z) = \frac{df}{dz} - e^z$. Is ths conformal, how can i find the conformal mapping of $z$ 
 plane?

Similarly what will be the case like how it changes if we take $w = f(z) = \int f(z) dz - e^z$?

Seeing the question it hints me to take $f$ as the form of exponential function in $z$ but i ma not getting the equation?

Also hinting to solve the differential equation in real variables and transforming to complex case?

Comment: I got $f(z) = ze^z$ ffor the derivative first problem

Comment: I don't understand your question. You assume $f$ is conformal and then you ask if $f$ is conformal ?

Comment: Sorry i hv to check it, i think it is not congormal, since at a point the derivative is zer